# Which are some little known catalogues whose objects can be observed during the night sky?

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing, star-gazing

We all know about the Messier catalogue. Little know or have heard about the Melotte catalogue. I am in search of those rare catalogues apart from Messier, NGC and IC with objects/sources that aren't mentioned in either of the aforementioned catalogues.

Comment: Here is a VERY large list of astronomical catalogs, how to judge which are "little known" in order to formulate a correct answer to your question? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_astronomical_catalogues

Comment: I really like the Dolidze-Dzimselejsvili catalogue (see https://www.astrobuysell.com/paul/DoDzClusters.htm). It is difficult to pronounce for us North Americans, which is a reason I like it, but all of its objects can be seen with good binoculars, although none of them is spectacular.